# String in cloudwatch metric

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I want to send nodenames(in the form of string like ip-xy-zx.eu-west-1.internal) as part of cloudwatch put-metric-data but when I try to use:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name nodename --namespace XYZ --unit None --value ${nodename} --timestamp $(date -u +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') it give me error:
```

> [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
> ##[error]Bash exited with code '255'.

What can be the best way to publish such kind of string to cloudwatch metrics?

Answer (score 0):

You may set `nodename` as a dimension when putting metrics to cloudwatch, here is an example:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data \
--namespace XYZ \
--dimensions nodename=${nodename} \
--unit None \
--timestamp $(date -u +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') \
...
```